# React event onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I've got an input that width changed on focus.

```
function Search({ searchValue, setSearchValue }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <svg
        className={styles.icon}
        height="512px"
        id="Layer_1"
        version="1.1"
        viewBox="0 0 512 512"
        width="512px"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M344.5,298c15-23.6,23.8-51.6,23.8-81.7c0-84.1-68.1-152.3-152.1-152.3C132.1,64,64,132.2,64,216.3  c0,84.1,68.1,152.3,152.1,152.3c30.5,0,58.9-9,82.7-24.4l6.9-4.8L414.3,448l33.7-34.3L339.5,305.1L344.5,298z M301.4,131.2  c22.7,22.7,35.2,52.9,35.2,85c0,32.1-12.5,62.3-35.2,85c-22.7,22.7-52.9,35.2-85,35.2c-32.1,0-62.3-12.5-85-35.2  c-22.7-22.7-35.2-52.9-35.2-85c0-32.1,12.5-62.3,35.2-85c22.7-22.7,52.9-35.2,85-35.2C248.5,96,278.7,108.5,301.4,131.2z" />
      </svg>
      <input
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={(event) => setSearchValue(event.target.value)}
        className={styles.input}
        placeholder="Поиск Пиццы"
      />
      {searchValue && (
        <svg
          onClick={(e) => setSearchValue('')}
          className={styles.clearIcon}
          height="512px"
          id="Layer_1"
          version="1.1"
          viewBox="0 0 512 512"
          width="512px"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M437.5,386.6L306.9,256l130.6-130.6c14.1-14.1,14.1-36.8,0-50.9c-14.1-14.1-36.8-14.1-50.9,0L256,205.1L125.4,74.5  c-14.1-14.1-36.8-14.1-50.9,0c-14.1,14.1-14.1,36.8,0,50.9L205.1,256L74.5,386.6c-14.1,14.1-14.1,36.8,0,50.9  c14.1,14.1,36.8,14.1,50.9,0L256,306.9l130.6,130.6c14.1,14.1,36.8,14.1,50.9,0C451.5,423.4,451.5,400.6,437.5,386.6z" />
        </svg>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and scss for this

```
.root {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 12px 20px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;

  &:focus {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 550px;
  }
}

.icon {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  top: 12px;
}

.clearIcon {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
```

but i need to click clearIcon twice to clear input block. First the window is reduced to the starting size, and then it is cleared. When I delete animation on focus, it works properly as I wanted. I think. that the problem is depending on this type of animation.

Sorry, i just learning.

Comment: could you please post a runnable script to your question?